# Error in Delete Function in Table using JSON

Tags: php

I am writing some functions for the delete button in my table, and I can't get it right. I don't know where did I go wrong and I hope it makes sense.

Here's my script:

```
function Delete(str){
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete this Information ?') == 1) {
        xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                if (xhttp.responseText == 1) {
                    alert('Information that have you selected has already been Deleted');
                }else{
                    alert('Error: Function');
                }
            }
        }
        xhttp.open("POST","DeleteInformation.php",true);
        xhttp.send("ID=" + str);
    }
}
```

Here's the php file
DeleteInformation.php

```
<?php
    include_once('config.php');
    include_once('mysql.php');

    $OpenMysql = new MySqlConnect(Host,User,Pass,Database);
    $ID = $OpenMysql->DataFilter(isset($_REQUEST['ID'])?$_REQUEST['ID']:'');
    $query = "Delete From items where itemcodes = '$ID'";
    $result = $OpenMysql->ExecuteQuery($query);

    if (!$result) {
        echo "True";
    }else{
        echo "False";
    }
?>
```

Comment: which is failing the ajax request or the php?

Comment: i think the problem is the php script ??

Comment: if you look at the console and network activity do you see the ajax request get sent correctly with the appropriate ID value? My guess would be the calls to `include_once` - have you altered the `include_path` at all or is it still as per default? In which directory are your files `config.php` and `mysql.php`??

Comment: there's nothing in the console and network activity

Answer (score 0):

The issue I think was the `Delete` function was trying to call an undeclared and undefined object `xhttp` - this should be assigned with a new instance of `XMLHttpRequest` so your ajax function would never have sent any data. Of course, if you had defined `xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest` before the code you have shown then that comment would not necessarily hold true.

As you did not show how you call the function I have emulated how it might be called to test the functionality in the demo below.

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();

        /* randomly echo 1 or 0 to emulate both states */
        echo rand(0,1);

        exit();
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ajax php delete</title>
        <script>
            function Delete(str){
                if( confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete this Information ?') == 1 ) {
                    /* This variable was not defined so you should have had an error, unless it was defined globally elsewhere */
                    var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

                    xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if ( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {
                            if ( this.responseText == 1 ) {
                                alert('Information that have you selected has already been Deleted');
                            }else{
                                console.error('Whoops - an error! %s',this.response);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    xhttp.open( "POST", location.href, true );//"DeleteInformation.php"
                    xhttp.send( "ID=" + str );
                }
            }
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
                Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('input[data-name="delete"]') ).forEach(function(bttn){
                    bttn.onclick=function(event){
                        /* call the `delete` function */
                        Delete.call( this, this.dataset.id );
                    }.bind( bttn )
                })
            },false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
        <?php
            for( $i=1; $i<=10; $i++ ){
                echo "
                    <input type='button' data-name='delete' data-id='$i' value='Delete'>";
            }
        ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

With regards to your PHP code - by default the `include_path` is probably set something like this `.;C:\php5\pear` which is not obviously useful as such. It is likely that you have set these files below (config,mysql) in the same working directory ( though that is a guess ) so unless you have modified the include path these calls below will fail. Personally I like to use a full path to included files  whenever possible ~ such as `require __DIR__ . '/somescript.php'`

If however you have altered the `include_path` using `set_include_path` then ignore previous comment and instead fcus upn the javascript - if you do not see a network(xhr) request in the console then the ajax function is not being called...

```
<?php
    /* this may or may not be correct  the files location is unknown */
    require __DIR__ . '/config.php';
    require __DIR__ .'/mysql.php';



    $id=!empty( $_POST['ID'] ) ? filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'ID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ) : false;
    if( $id ){
        /*
            Host, User, Pass, Database
            Are these defined as constants in config.php or mysql.php??
        */
        $OpenMysql = new MySqlConnect( Host, User, Pass, Database );
        $ID=$OpenMysql->DataFilter( $id ); //? no idea what this does

        $query = "Delete from `items` where `itemcodes` = '$ID'";
        $result = $OpenMysql->ExecuteQuery( $query );

        echo $result ? 'true' : 'false';
    }
?>
```

Hope you find the above useful in resolving your issue